# Firebird JPA retornando valores null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, firebird

Quando tento pegar algum registro do banco, alguns campos vem nulos, ainda que na tabela não estejam nulos!

Alguma ideia do que pode estar ocasionando este comportamento?

Estou usando **Java 8**, **Hibernate 5.2.4**, **Jaybird 3.0.3**.

Assim que estou pegando os dados de Pessoa:

```
Pessoa p = manager.find(Pessoa.class, 20829);
```

Minha PU está assim:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:firebirdsql://192.168.56.101:3050/questorteste?encoding=ISO8859_1" />  
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SYSDBA" />  
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="masterkey" />  
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver" />
```

Meu EntityManagerProducer

```
public class EntityManagerProducer {
  private EntityManagerFactory factory;

  public EntityManagerProducer() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Firebird");
  }

  public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
    return factory.createEntityManager();
  }
}
```

Entidade Pessoa

```
    @Entity
    public class Pessoa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2991232997484581117L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "codigopessoa")
    private Integer codigopessoa;

    @Column(name = "NOMEPESSOA")
    private String nomepessoa;

    @Column(name = "TIPOINSCR")
    private Short tipoinscr;

    @Column(name = "INSCRFEDERAL")
    private String inscrfederal;

    @Column(name = "SUFRAMA")
    private String suframa;

    @Column(name = "SIGLAESTADO")
    private String siglaestado;

    @Column(name = "CODIGOMUNIC")
    private Short codigomunic;

    @Column(name = "tipofornecedor")
    private Short tipofornecedor;

    @Column(name = "INSCRESTAD")
    private String inscrestad;

    @Column(name = "INSCRMUNIC")
    private String inscrmunic;

    @Column(name = "CODIGOATIVFEDERAL")
    private String codigoativfederal;

    public Pessoa() {
    }

    public Integer getCodigopessoa() {
        return this.codigopessoa;
    }

    public void setCodigopessoa(Integer codigopessoa) {
        System.out.println("setCodigopessoa");
        this.codigopessoa = codigopessoa;
    }

    public String getNomepessoa() {
        return this.nomepessoa;
    }

    public void setNomepessoa(String nomepessoa) {
        System.out.println("setNomepessoa");
        this.nomepessoa = nomepessoa;
    }

    public Short getTipoinscr() {
        return this.tipoinscr;
    }

    public void setTipoinscr(Short tipoinscr) {
        System.out.println("setTipoinscr");
        this.tipoinscr = tipoinscr;
    }

    public String getInscrfederal() {
        return this.inscrfederal;
    }

    public void setInscrfederal(String inscrfederal) {
        System.out.println("setInscrfederal");
        this.inscrfederal = inscrfederal;
    }

    public String getSuframa() {
        return this.suframa;
    }

    public void setSuframa(String suframa) {
        System.out.println("setSuframa");
        this.suframa = suframa;
    }

    public String getSiglaestado() {
        return this.siglaestado;
    }

    public void setSiglaestado(String siglaestado) {
        System.out.println("setSiglaestado");
        this.siglaestado = siglaestado;
    }

    public Short getCodigomunic() {
        return this.codigomunic;
    }

    public void setCodigomunic(Short codigomunic) {
        System.out.println("setCodigomunic");
        this.codigomunic = codigomunic;
    }

    public Short getTipofornecedor() {
        return this.tipofornecedor;
    }

    public void setTipofornecedor(Short tipofornecedor) {
        System.out.println("setTipofornecedor");
        this.tipofornecedor = 2;
    }

    public String getInscrestad() {
        return this.inscrestad;
    }

    public void setInscrestad(String inscrestad) {
        System.out.println("setInscrestad");
        this.inscrestad = inscrestad;
    }

    public String getInscrmunic() {
        return this.inscrmunic;
    }

    public void setInscrmunic(String inscrmunic) {
        System.out.println("setInscrmunic");
        this.inscrmunic = inscrmunic;
    }

    public String getCodigoativfederal() {
        return this.codigoativfederal;
    }

    public void setCodigoativfederal(String codigoativfederal) {
        System.out.println("setCodigoativfederal");
        this.codigoativfederal = codigoativfederal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Achei o problema.
Estava na minha string de conexão, eu apotava para um banco e comparava com outro... Chupei bala...